# JavaScript Animate Sprite Sheet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sprite-sheet

I have no experience with Sprite Sheets or animating via CSS, and I have my own sprite sheet (found [here](http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/dragonFire.png)), and I researched plenty.

Only thing useful I got out of tutorials is that you can use a HTML5 Canvas and JavaScript/CSS to make it animate. The whole point of this is so that I can make a `img` loop a animation once, then change the `src` to [this](http://www.thegaminghideout.com/school/dragon.gif). Again, I did plenty of research and got little knowledge. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: you don't need canvas for that. jquery alone can offset background positions of elements just fine without canvas.

Comment: [Try this excellent blog post](http://mr-easy.ml/blog/2017/06/26/creating-spritesheet-animation-in-html5-canvas-using-javascript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [steps in CSS animations](http://designmodo.com/steps-css-animations/). It allows to recreate an animated gif, just with a sprite sheet that gets shifted every few ms.